# Backbone Model Binder: attributes aren't on the model

Tags: backbone.js, model-binding, marionette, backbone-views

Im using Backbone marionette with backbone model binder.

With the code below, if the defaults of select + input[type=date] are done and the user doesn't change them, the model attributes comes back empty when the user clicks save. If the user edits on field and clicks save, that one field is set on the model attribute.

```
define(["marionette", "underscore", "text!app/templates/sicknesses/form.html", "app/models/sickness", "app/collections/users"], function(Marionette, _, Template, Model, Users) {
  "use strict"
  return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    events: {
      "click #createButton": "onClickSave"
    },
    _modelBinder: undefined,
    initialize: function(options) {
      var that
      this._modelBinder = new Backbone.ModelBinder()
      this.mode = 'create'
      this.users = new Users()
      this.users.on("reset", this.render, this)
      this.users.fetch()
      this.model = new Model()
    },
    onClickSave: function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.model.attributes)
    },
    render: function() {
      var bindings, html
      if (this.users.length > 0) {
        bindings = {
          start_date: "#start_date",
          end_date: "#end_date",
          sicknote: "#sicknote",
          user: "#user"
        }
        html = _.template($(Template).html(), {
          model: this.model.toJSON(),
          users: this.users.toJSON(),
          mode: this.mode
        })
        this.$el.html(html)
        this._modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.$el, bindings)
      }
      return this
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct behavior. The data should be driven by the model and not the view.

From the [Doc](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder)

- “The model's attributes are bound are copied from the model to bound elements when the bind() function is called. View element default values are not copied to the model when bind() is called. That type of behavior usually belongs in the Backbone.Model defaults block.”

We’ve a similar use-case to initialize the model with the View and there is a feature added to copy the initial data from the View to the model

- “If you do need to have values copied from the view to the model when bind() is called I would first question why. In most situations, especially for single page web apps, it's almost always better to let your models drive the behavior of the app instead of the views. If you need this behavior, you can use the 4th optional parameter to the bind() function. {initialCopyDirection: Backbone.ModelBinder.Constants.ViewToModel} You can also specify this behavior as the default for all ModelBinder's by calling Backbone.ModelBinder.SetOptions({initialCopyDirection: Backbone.ModelBinder.Constants.ViewToModel});”

Need to update the bind call to add the 4th param:

```
this._modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.$el, bindings, {initialCopyDirection: Backbone.ModelBinder.Constants.ViewToModel});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Are you implying that my model defaults should define the preselected values and not the html form? AKA a select with no preset value defaults to the first item in the list

?

Comment: It is really up to you. If you keep what you have, you need to add 'initialCopyDirection: Backbone.ModelBinder.Constants.ViewToModel' when call bind so that the initial value in the view can be copied to the model.

Comment: Great thanks, that fixed it. Apart from the input[type=date] which comes back empty. I wonder if its todo with the implementation of it.

Comment: You meant the view is empty by the time bind is called?  I've issue with <input type='range'> and using it in JQM env. It is timing related issue.  See this if it helps. https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder/issues/152

Comment: Tried the above code and no matter what the only html element that doesnt work properly is this: <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="dateField">

Comment: if you can post a jsfiddle, we can take a look more closely